# How to place mesh at the corner

Tags: mesh, add-on

I want to place my mesh at the corner so that it look with the reference image below.

[image]

[image]

I tried with the shrikwrap modifier. For me did not work. I tried with the jewel craft addon but it has only X,Y,Z AND -X,-Y,-Z. It does not fix on both x and y axis same time.

[Jewelcraft addon video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoeWbrNPGPU) @10.22 it show how to add mesh on curve but did not work for me. Any help with the help this addon or other method work for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try 2 things:

- Gradually decrease the weight of the group so that the *Shrinkwrap* influence will be smoother.
- Put the *Subsurf* modifier above the *Shrinkwrap*, choose the *Nearest Surface Point* mode in the *Shrinkwrap*.

It won't look like your reference image but you need to improve a bit the modeling.

[image]

Comment: while the top and the bottom mesh not covering the corner as seen above in the image.

Comment: it will if you move the object a bit away from the corner, but in that case it will change its deformation on its sides... maybe it will be easier to simply model this shape, Shrinkwrap can't be perfect

Comment: Any other method can fix the issues or can look similar to the reference image

Comment: I'm not sure there's any easy way to do it, except maybe with addons like Surface Follow or Mira? Maybe take a look at those... Do you have a reason not to do it manually? Use the Proportional Editing option, you can even use the Mesh Deform with a cage if you feel more comfortable with this kind of method.

Comment: I tried with the curve modifier and then with the shrinkwrap to get this result. https://imgur.com/a/k39epzb

Comment: nice, maybe give a detailed answer!